# Global minimum versus local minima solution with Python Gekko

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

A simple optimization example has 2 local minima at `(0,0,8)` with objective `936.0` and `(7,0,0)` with objective `951.0`. What are techniques to use local optimizers in Python Gekko (`APOPT`,`BPOPT`,`IPOPT`) to find a global solution?

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.Array(m.Var,3,lb=0)
x1,x2,x3 = x
m.Minimize(1000-x1**2-2*x2**2-x3**2-x1*x2-x1*x3)
m.Equations([8*x1+14*x2+7*x3==56,
             x1**2+x2**2+x3**2>=25])
m.solve(disp=False)
res=[print(f'x{i+1}: {xi.value[0]}') for i,xi in enumerate(x)]
print(f'Objective: {m.options.objfcnval:.2f}')
```

This produces a local minimum:

```
x1: 7.0
x2: 0.0
x3: 0.0
Objective: 951.00
```

There are solvers for a global optimum such as `BARON`, `COCOS`, `GlobSol`, `ICOS`, `LGO`, `LINGO`, and `OQNLP`, but what are some quick strategies that can be used with a local optimizer to search for a global solution? Some industrial applications have highly nonlinear models that haven't been fully tested for global solutions in control and design. Can the strategy be parallelized in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Multi-start** approaches (using random starting points) can be useful. No guarantee about global optimality, but at least you are protected a bit against some embarrassingly bad local solutions. Some local NLP solvers have this built-in (e.g. Knitro).

Here is Python code for the example using a multi-start method to get the global solution. It uses multi-threading to parallelize the search.

```py
import numpy as np
import threading
import time, random
from gekko import GEKKO

class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, id, xg):
        s = self
        s.id = id
        s.m = GEKKO(remote=False)
        s.xg = xg
        s.objective = float('NaN')

        # initialize variables
        s.m.x = s.m.Array(s.m.Var,3,lb=0)
        for i in range(3):
            s.m.x[i].value = xg[i]
        s.m.x1,s.m.x2,s.m.x3 = s.m.x

        # Equations
        s.m.Equation(8*s.m.x1+14*s.m.x2+7*s.m.x3==56)
        s.m.Equation(s.m.x1**2+s.m.x2**2+s.m.x3**2>=25)

        # Objective
        s.m.Minimize(1000-s.m.x1**2-2*s.m.x2**2-s.m.x3**2
                     -s.m.x1*s.m.x2-s.m.x1*s.m.x3)

        # Set solver option
        s.m.options.SOLVER = 1

        threading.Thread.__init__(s)

    def run(self):
        print('Running application ' + str(self.id) + '\n')
        self.m.solve(disp=False,debug=0) # solve
        # Retrieve objective if successful
        if (self.m.options.APPSTATUS==1):
            self.objective = self.m.options.objfcnval
        else:
            self.objective = float('NaN')
        self.m.cleanup()

# Optimize at mesh points
x1_ = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 3.0)
x2_ = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 3.0)
x3_ = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 3.0)
x1,x2,x3 = np.meshgrid(x1_,x2_,x3_)

threads = [] # Array of threads

# Load applications
id = 0
for i in range(x1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x1.shape[1]):
        for k in range(x1.shape[2]):
            xg = (x1[i,j,k],x2[i,j,k],x3[i,j,k])
            # Create new thread
            threads.append(ThreadClass(id, xg))
            # Increment ID
            id += 1

# Run applications simultaneously as multiple threads
# Max number of threads to run at once
max_threads = 8
for t in threads:
    while (threading.activeCount()>max_threads):
        # check for additional threads every 0.01 sec
        time.sleep(0.01)
    # start the thread
    t.start()

# Check for completion
mt = 10.0 # max time (sec)
it = 0.0  # time counter
st = 1.0  # sleep time (sec)
while (threading.active_count()>=3):
    time.sleep(st)
    it = it + st
    print('Active Threads: ' + str(threading.active_count()))
    # Terminate after max time
    if (it>=mt):
        break

# Initialize array for objective
obj = np.empty_like(x1)

# Retrieve objective results
id = 0
id_best = 0; obj_best = 1e10
for i in range(x1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x1.shape[1]):
        for k in range(x1.shape[2]):
            obj[i,j,k] = threads[id].objective
            if obj[i,j,k]<obj_best:
                id_best = id
                obj_best = obj[i,j,k]
            id += 1

print(obj)
print(f'Best objective {obj_best}')
print(f'Solution {threads[id_best].m.x}')
```

It produces the global solution:

```
Best objective 936.0
Solution [[0.0] [0.0] [8.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to multi-start random searches there are Bayesian, Genetic Algorithm, and other methods in hyperparameter optimization packages such as `hyperopt`. This [Medium article](https://medium.com/criteo-engineering/hyper-parameter-optimization-algorithms-2fe447525903) has a nice overview of hyperparameter search methods. Below is code to find the global optimum in Python with Gekko. There are suggestions to parallelize: [Python and HyperOpt: How to make multi-process grid searching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370879/python-and-hyperopt-how-to-make-multi-process-grid-searching) although I haven't tried these. Here is the specific example with a Tree-structured Parzen estimator.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp
from hyperopt import STATUS_OK, STATUS_FAIL

# Define the search space for the hyperparameters
space = {'x1': hp.quniform('x1', 0, 10, 3),
         'x2': hp.quniform('x2', 0, 10, 3),
         'x3': hp.quniform('x3', 0, 10, 3)}

def objective(params):
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    x = m.Array(m.Var,3,lb=0)
    x1,x2,x3 = x
    x1.value = params['x1']
    x2.value = params['x2']
    x3.value = params['x3']
    m.Minimize(1000-x1**2-2*x2**2-x3**2-x1*x2-x1*x3)
    m.Equations([8*x1+14*x2+7*x3==56,
                 x1**2+x2**2+x3**2>=25])
    m.options.SOLVER = 1
    m.solve(disp=False,debug=False)
    obj = m.options.objfcnval
    if m.options.APPSTATUS==1:
        s=STATUS_OK
    else:
        s=STATUS_FAIL
    m.cleanup()
    return {'loss':obj, 'status': s, 'x':x}

best = fmin(objective, space, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=50)
sol = objective(best)
print(f"Solution Status: {sol['status']}")
print(f"Objective: {sol['loss']:.2f}")
print(f"Solution: {sol['x']}")
```

Hyperopt finds the global solution with gekko as the local minimizer:

```
Solution Status: ok
Objective: 936.00
Solution: [[0.0] [0.0] [8.0]]
```